# How to create Index faster on a very large table with 118M records

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

How to create an Index faster on a very large table with 118M records, I need to create an index on 2 date columns. After creating an index do we have to gather stats or does oracle gather stats automatically.

What would be the best method to gather stats much faster?

Comment: Creating an index should be a one-time operation.  There are no silver-bullets for making it faster, and it will probably complete before you find an answer.  It won't hurt to run stats afterward, but oracle has a built-in job to run stats every night on the tables that it deems need it.  BTW, you've tagged 2 different versions of oracle.  Which of those out-of-support versions is relevant to your question?   You've also tagged SQL Dev, which is totally irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @EdStevens We are Using Oracle 13C Edition

Comment: _"We are Using Oracle 13C Edition"_    There is no Oracle 13c.  They went from 12 straight to 18.  So what ARE you using?  And why do you think you are using something that does not exist?

Comment: @EdStevens I am sorry my bad this is the current version we are using.                                Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
"CORE 12.2.0.1.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the resources (CPU etc), you can build the index in parallel. Stats are automatically collected on the index during the build.

Comment: Thank you ,  Can you let me now if this is the correct method to do it  CREATE INDEX /*+ parallel enable_parallel_dml*/ EDWFIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_PART_70 ON EDWFIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP (SRC_CREATED_DATE ASC);

Comment: CREATE INDEX EDWFIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_PART_70 ON EDWFIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP (SRC_CREATED_DATE ASC) PARALLEL <x>, where x is the DoP you want to use.